# C code with ncurses compiled with libtinfo dependency

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I've recently written a minesweeper implementation in C using ncurses on linux; everything works fine on my pc, but if I try to give the compiled binaries to someone else they often get the error:

`error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If I have them recompile the code everything's fine. By looking around I discovered it's an issue with the separation between libtinfo and libncurses. It can be solved by making a few simlinks, but it's a solution only viable when the user has root privileges.

As of here (and other sources), http://www.cyberspice.org.uk/blog/2009/12/24/tinfo-about-dash/ , it seems that it's an issue that can be solved by writing the code in a different way or maybe compiling differently. I'd rather be able to solve the problem that way than forcing people to make simlinks.

Any pointers in the right direction to understand how to solve my issue? I can add any code or details, if needed, but it seems an overkill to post *everything*, so please tell me what can be added (if needed) to better understand the problem.

The only thing I'm posting for now is the makefile:

```
CC=gcc -std=gnu89 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
CFLAGS=-c -g
LDFLAGS=-lncurses

NAME=campo_ex
OBJECTS=error.o interface.o utilities.o main.o grid.o

DEBUG_NAME=debug
DEBUG_OBJECTS=error.o interface.o utilities.o debug.o

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.c interface.h grid.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c

debug.o: debug.c interface.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) debug.c

error.o: error.c error.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) error.c

utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) utilities.c

interface.o: interface.c interface.h error.h utilities.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) interface.c

grid.o: grid.c grid.h error.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) grid.c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @-rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(NAME) $(DEBUG_NAME) $(DEBUG_OBJECTS)

.PHONY: debug
debug: $(DEBUG_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(DEBUG_NAME) $(DEBUG_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: If you really want to distribute binaries you could staticly link the executable so you don't have any shared library issues.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the extra space, but it would have surely been a viable alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executing `readelf -d` on your compiled program will probably show the connection to libtinfo.so.5

```
$ readelf -d /path/to/your/program  | grep NEEDED
[...]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libtinfo.so.5]
[...]
```

This may be pulled in because your `libncurses.so` pulls it in somehow, e.g. by containing something like:

```
INPUT(... -ltinfo)
```

(Or something similar. I can just guess here..)

You can try adding `-Wl,--as-needed` to your `LDFLAGS` and hope that your program is not referencing any symbols from `libtinfo` directly so that the linker does not need to add a dependency for `libtinfo` to your program.

```
LDFLAGS=-Wl,--as-needed -lncurses
```

Recompile with new `LDFLAGS` and check again with `readelf -d` if it got compiled and linked without errors.

Using `--as-needed` can be problematic if `libncurses` uses symbols from `libtinfo` but does not include a dependency to `libtinfo` itself. If this happens your build will fail and complain about `unreferenced symbols` or similar..

So if this does not work you may want to fix your curses installation or use the (in my opinion very dirty) symlink hack you already mentioned. Or let users compile the code on their systems - If you do not want to share code you can also just do the linking on the target system.

To fix the symlink-need-root-privileges issue you can also add a `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib'` to your linker flags and expand the library search path of your program. This enables users to install your binary to `/home/user/bin/program` and search libraries in `/home/user/bin/../lib`. So they can do "dirty" symlink hacks in `/home/user/lib`.

It is always problematic when distributing binaries only.

Comment: The additional flags to the linker did the trick. And nice idea about the privileges part, hadn't thought of that. I'll be sure to remember if I ever need it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After searching a lot I realized that the cause of the problem is that the `libtinfo` functionality is now embedded inside the `libncurses` library.

You can solve it by doing this 2 simple steps:

1. Go to the directory where your libncurses shared libs are located (generally within your toolchain)
2. Create the following links

and compile again:

```
sudo ln -s libncurses.so.6 libtinfo.so.6  
sudo ln -s libncurses.so.6 libtinfo.so
```

The idea was taken from [the following Launchpad site](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncurses/+bug/259139).

Comment: OP's question is about something different (and this answer wouldn't work).

Comment: Wow. Great finding.